# How do you expose methods from NativeScript custom components?

Tags: nativescript

I want to expose a method from a custom component in a NativeScript project. Here is the conceptual setup:

**MyComponent.xml**

`<StackLayout loaded="loaded"> ...UI markup... </StackLayout>`

**MyComponent.ts**

`export function loaded(args) { //do stuff };
export function myCustomMethod() { //do more stuff };`

**MyPage.xml**

`<Page xmlns:widget="..." loaded="loaded">
   <widget:MyComponent id="myComponent" />
</Page>`

**MyPage.ts**

`export function loaded(args) {
   let page = <Page>args.object;
   let widget = page.getViewById("myComponent");
   widget.myCustomMethod(); //<--THIS DOES NOT WORK
}`

Question: How do I properly expose the `myCustomMethod` on the custom component so that the hosting page can access and call it via JavaScript?

By default, when trying to get a reference to the custom component on the page, a reference to the custom component's layout container is returned (in this example, a `StackLayout`).

So, as a workaround, I am doing this:

**MyComponent.ts**

`export function loaded(args) {
   let stackLayout = <StackLayout>args.object; //Layout container
   stackLayout.myCustomMethod = myCustomMethod; //Attach custom method to StackLayout
}`

It's a bit of a hack, but it's working. Is there any better way to expose custom component methods short of creating a super class for the layout container?

**UPDATE**

To be more accurate, the custom component has instance properties, so the eventual solution would need to support a scenario like...

**MyComponent.ts**

`let isStarted = false;
export function loaded(args){ // do stuff };
export function myCustomMethod() { isStarted = true; };`

Comment: Even I'm interested in this

Comment: Todd any solution nowaday?

Comment: Switching to TypeScript made this quite a bit more natural/easier to solve. If I have a "visual" custom component today, I usually extend a StackLayout and then add my new public methods/properties. So my primary recommendation is to start using TypeScript with NativeScript (if you're not already).

Answer (score 0):

As the method you want to reuse is not coupled to your customCompoenent, you can create a common file and require it where needed and reuse the exposed methods accordingly. Or you can directly import your MyComponent.ts and reuse its exported methods (not so good idea as you will probably have access to all exposed methods of your MyCompoennt.ts like onLoaded, onNavigationgTo, etc.)

For example:

in your ***navigator.ts*** (or if you prefer to your MyComponent.ts)

```
import frame = require("ui/frame");
export function navigateBack() {
    frame.goBack();
}
```

and then reuse it where needed like this:

***MyPage.ts***

```
import navigatorModule = require("navigator");

export function goBack(args: observable.EventData) {
    navigatorModule.goBack(); // we are reusing goBack() from navigator.ts
}
```

Another applicable option is to use MVVM pattern and expose your methods via the binding context.

Comment: I will experiment with this. Ultimately, in my case, there is "instance" state for the custom component. Not sure if this approach would work...but I will investigate and report back. Thanks!